# Shorten words and strings to specific length in Python keeping them as recognizable as possible?

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to render a lot of different strings on a 32x32px canvas. Currently I'm trying to use `pyvips` but it lacks [support for character wrap in Pango](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/1791). Thus, for now I'm trying to shorten separate words. The desired word length limit is about 8 characters most of the time.

*Simple* disemvowelment doesn't work when the word is starting with a vowel or has repeating vowels. I guess additional cut can be done by deduplicating characters. But the main problem is the lack of algorithm / heuristic for deciding what's less important, should be removed first and **stopping at certain word / string length**. The task seems so common that I'd expect there being some library already available. However I cannot find it: `disevowel` and `shorten` searches didn't yield anything useful.

For example, if I wanted to shorten `Eerie Aaron and an aardvark` to 20 characters, I'd go with something like `Erie Aron and ardvrk`.

Also, I've seen it implemented in the Draft Fortress game, but it's closed-source.